# Using Text Indent with Text Align

Tags: html, css

I used text-align right in my footer to position my text and unordered list all the way to the bottom right of my page.  I would like to have a little bit of space between the text on the bottom right and the edge of my page.  After using text align-right, whatever I do, the last part of my text always pushes right up to the edge of my window in the bottom right.  I tried playing with the right and left margin but so far this hasn't solved the problem, here is a jsfiddle with my code: http://jsfiddle.net/sdaless/PM5Na/  If anyone can help I'd appreciate it, thanks!

Here is my footer css and html:

html:

```
<footer>
    <div id="footer-container">
        <ul id="footerlist">
            <hr>
            <li><a href="#">Advertising Programs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Business Solutions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy &amp; Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">+Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Google</a></li>
</footer>
```

css:

```
#footer-container {

    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: right;

}

#footer-container ul li a {
    color:#656565;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 0 7px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

#footerlist li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;  
}
```

Comment: do you test padding-right?

Comment: Use margin-right like in my answer

Comment: Yeah, I tried the padding right in in all the id's in my css and none impacted the position.

Comment: Did you miss `</div>` there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your html to this:

```
<footer>
    <div id="footer-container">
        <ul id="footerlist">
            <hr>
            <li><a href="#">Advertising Programs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Business Solutions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Privacy &amp; Terms</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">+Google</a></li>
            <li style='margin-right: 10px'><a href="#">About Google</a></li>
</footer>
```

Or use this css:

```
#footerlist li:last-child {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! quick side question, is there a more accepted way for doing this?  I'm trying to learn the best semantics, from what I've been reading the general rule of thumb is to try and use your css as much as you can and limit the amount of styling in your html.

Comment: When it fixes rendering position this does not fix original layout error of #footer-container:, this `width:100% + padding-left:5px + padding-right:5px` is always greater than view width. So the view will always show horizontal scrollbar when it really not needed.

Comment: Use the pseudo class :last-child

Answer (score 0):

use folllowing code:

```
<footer>
<div id="footer-container">
    <ul id="footerlist" style="padding-right:10px">
        <hr>
        <li><a href="#">Advertising Programs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Business Solutions</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Privacy &amp; Terms</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">+Google</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Google</a></li>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either do this:

```
#footer-container {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2px;
    left:0; right:0; /* width:100%; */
    text-align: right;
}
```

or this

```
#footer-container {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 2px;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* so width:100% defines border box  */
    text-align: right;
}
```